# Is it possible to generate a sine wave formula using values from an array?

Tags: arduino, wave, sine, arduino-uno, code

so we have an Arduino code which includes an array, is it possible to make those array disappear [in the code] and instead formulate a sine wave formula for those [array] to make the output in sine waveform? Yes or No? if yes, how can I make it possible? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you entirely understand how arduino works. And what does it mean to make array disappear in code and appear as a sine wave? What? No idea what you mean, but arduino CANNOT output sine wave or any other voltage. All its pins output either strictly 0V or strictly 5V. PWM output (which is analogwrite in arduino) is nothing more but an output of 0V and 5V very quickly in different proportions. But it's still 0-5-0-5-0-5.

Comment: Microchip has an old [App Note 543](https://www.microchip.com/wwwcategory/taxonomysearch/#/TaxonomySearch/GetSearchResults/NA/NA/AN543%20-%20Tone%20Generation) which describes generating DTMF dial tones in an 8-bit PIC without using a sine lookup array. As far as I recall, their method uses a digital filter algorithm configured as a resonator.

Comment: @Scathach is the output frequency fixed or does it need to be variable in operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to reduce a large array that represents a smooth curve into a shorter array of key points in that curve, and to use interpolation to generate the other points. Linear interpolation is the simplest to use.

One question needed for the design is how much error you can tolerate on the interpolated points, the more accuracy needed, the longer the array. Another is a speed/space tradeoff, where saving deltas in the table saves a little calculation, but doubles the size of the table. Implementing cubic interpolation reduces the size of the table, at the expense of increased calculation time.

It is feasible to generate sine from scratch through the COORDIC algorithm, or from a Taylor series approximation, both requiring very little storage. COORDIC is especially well suited to integer arithmetic.

It's worth pointing out that Arduino does not have a true analogue output. You'll need to either use an external DAC, or the use the AnalogWrite function to write to a PWM pin which will be capable of generating only very low frequency sinewaves.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to implement a sine wave that are much more efficient and more accurate than a look table or Cordic

A much better method is using complex phasor rotation. This only requires 1 complex multiply per sample (or 4 real multiplies). This works particularly well with magnitude drift correction.

For the math details see for example: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1087/3997 and a a code example is at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/9868/3997

Comment: @ChrisStratton: if another Stack Exchange answer complete answers the question is the expectation that you should copy & paste instead of linking ? That gets tricky since the different sites have different support for things like Latex Math

Comment: Fair enough. I regurgitated some stuff from the linked replies but I'm not going to reformat all the math parts here. If that's not good enough, feel free to delete.